# Binding WPF Checked List Box to ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Datagrid` in my view which successfully binds to my `ObservableCollection`. I now have a `CheckedListBox` (Extended WPF Toolkit) which I want to bind to the same `ObservableCollection`. Something in my `XAML` binding isn't quite right as am getting the class name rather than the value in my UI `CheckedListBox` at run time?

```
  <Grid>
     <GroupBox>
         <xctk:CheckListBox DataContext="{StaticResource ArticleDataGridViewModel}"  Name="checkListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ModelviewArticleObservableList}" DisplayMemberPath="ArticleHeader" />
     </GroupBox>                
   </Grid>
```

Thanks

Comment: This is the tag for the Extended WPF Toolkit: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I just changed it to a normal ListBox & the binding was successful...

Comment: look into what the xctk wraps it in or.. make your own checked list box by creating a data template inside. pretty easy to do :)